# Change default file permission for mounted Windows network share

Tags: linux, macos, network-shares, file-permissions

I'm on OS X and mount a network share from my Windows XP machine. Files by default have the `rwx` (`700`) permissions. What OS X option I need to change, that the files will have `rw` (`600`) permission?

Maybe this question also applies for Linux mounting a Windows network share.

Answer (score 1):

```
mount.cifs //server/share /mnt -o user=boettcher,file_mode=0600
```

works for me on linux client and an XP server. More information: `man smbmount` or `man mount.cifs`